# What file format to use for Django configuration which can be frequently updated using Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django application where I need a configuration file.

I want key value pairs in there, where values can be updated using django form fields.

Which one is the best file format, so that read and write is easy (user can update values using a django form).

I have Value something like below:

```
<Key_MAX_RANGE>=**<VALUE_MAX_RANGE>**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to serialize to JSON or YAML. However, if you want a more human-readable format that is more strictly a set of key-value pairs, you might use the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html) module. It reads and writes INI-style configuration files, like this:

```
[section]
key = value
```

Here is an example of writing out a configuration file based on a form's `cleaned_data`:

```
In [39]: from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

In [40]: cleaned_data = {'foo': 'bar', 'bob': 'ann'}

In [41]: config = SafeConfigParser()

In [42]: config.add_section('my_form')

In [43]: for field, value in cleaned_data.iteritems():
   ....:     config.set('my_form', field, value)
   ....:

In [44]: with open('example.cfg', 'w') as config_file:
   ....:     config.write(config_file)
   ....: 

In [45]: cat example.cfg
[my_form]
bob = ann
foo = bar
```